# Sideload with ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Can someone explain why the side loading in this case don't work, I dont get any errors but the followers are not rendered and when I try to check it in the `setupController` method using `model.get('followers').content`, I got an empty array.

This is the loaded JSON:

```
{
  user: {
    id: 1,
    follower_ids: [2,3,4],
    name: 'someUserName'
  }
  followers: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'someUserName'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'someUserName'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'someUserName'
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is my User model

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    followers: DS.hasMany('App.User')
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the guide shows, the key for the ids must be `followers` instead of `follower_ids`. So with a JSON look like this it works:

```
{
  user: {
    id: 1,
    followers: [2,3,4],
    name: 'someUserName'
  }
  followers: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'someUserName'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'someUserName'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'someUserName'
    }
  ]
}
```